# Stop Pry from putting each value of a returned array on a new line?

Tags: ruby, pry

I watched the RubyConf 2013 talk on Pry and I have decided I ought to give it a good try.

I am working with some large arrays.  It would be easier to work with my code if Pry would display returned arrays the way IRB does.  What seems odd is that pry will not add newlines if the number of chars in the displayed array is small but it will add them when the number of chars in the displayed array surpasses some threshold (appears to be 26 chars in my case).  Does anybody know how to make Pry stop doing this?

IRB:

```
main 001(0) > a = [] #=> []
main 002(0) > (1..100).each{|i| a << i} #=> 1..100
main 003(0) > a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Pry:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = []
=> []
[2] pry(main)> (1..26).each{ a << 1 }
=> 1..26
[3] pry(main)> a
=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[4] pry(main)> a << 1
=> [1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1]
```

Comment: pry is jumping into the inspection mode, so you can navigate large objects. if you just want to have some "output" you can do something like this `(1..100).to_a.to_s`

Comment: if it's like irb, then try `a << 1; nil` to avoid it writing out the entire structure when you're done is what I do

Comment: It is like irb in that you can append `;nil` ...But, I would like avoid writing code specifically for use in the interpreter as much as possible. Also, it is sometimes helpful to see my array -- scrolling up through a thousand lines with one short array value on each line is a lot more of a pain than looking at all the values on a single wrapped line.  It is nice to be able to take a bit of code from somewhere else and just run it without having to modify the code to make the output readable.

Comment: @phoet Is this behavior documented anywhere?  Searching the repo for either 'inspection' or 'mode' didn't reveal anything useful.
Anyway, I don't want to just have 'some output'.  I want to be able to paste in code from my application and run it and have the output be readable without having to doing something like you suggest to every line that returns an array.

Comment: you enter a "pager" like less and have all the beautiful commands available for searching, paging etc. what exactly is it that you want to be "readable". for me, the output is perfectly fine. if you type `h` in that mode, you will see all the options available to you.

Comment: @rogerdpack in Pry you can just end the line with a `;` you do not need to put `; nil` :P

Answer (score 7):

Edit your [`.pryrc` file](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc) to include

```
Pry.config.print = proc { |output, value| output.puts "=> #{value.inspect}" }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get `pry` to print inline like robertjlooby's answer, but retain the pretty-printing:

```
# in your .pryrc
Pry.config.print = lambda do |output, value, _pry_|
    _pry_.pager.open do |pager|
    pager.print _pry_.config.output_prefix
    Pry::ColorPrinter.pp(value, pager, 9e99)
  end
end
```

adapted from [`pry` source](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/9622b00689a6b3ccf969153f36b23f46341ba416/lib/pry.rb#L21)